# Django - creating parent and child simultaneously

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using Django 1.7 and have a form which contains a parent model as well as a one-to-many relationship to a child model.  For instance, I want users to be able to create a Meeting and add Members to that meeting at the same time.  I want to be able to use ajax to retrieve a list of active members and have the user select those within the Meeting form before saving, then save everything all at once.  Is there a way to set up the form with formsets or something without having to do a lot of javascript trickery?

Keep in mind this will need to retain the selected members even if the form gets submitted with invalid data for the Meeting instance that's being created and has to be re-rendered.

Example models (untested):

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    created = models.DateField()

class MeetingMember(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    meeting = models.ForeignKey('Meeting')
```

Comment: What do you mean by active member? user.active to be True?

Comment: I just meant a list of valid members -- the ajax part is the easy part -- I'll just have a separate view to retrieve the members I want.  What I'm more focused on is the form itself, and being able to create instances of both models at once.

Comment: I think what an active member is important here. Nevertheless, why aren't you simply making just the ``Meeting`` model with a M2M field to ``User`` and a FK again to ``User`` ? Then you will create a meeting and select the users with checkboxes

Comment: Because if I click the Save button and the Meeting model doesn't validate, what happens to the selected Users in the form?

Comment: nothing? you will only see the form errors?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the inline formset mechanism in django? I think this will do everything you want, including without the JS voodoo

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Comment: It seems awkward to use formsets for this.  I want it to provide a list of each possible Member that can be added to the Meeting.  With a formset I'd have to provide several initial "forms", one for each of the possible Members, with a checkbox beside each one?

Comment: The example you shared is for editing the members for an already created meeting, not for creating both entities simultaneously.